# ASP.NET counter in loop

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a `foreach` loop in my ASP.NET code and I am trying to add a counter by adding `@counter++` at the end of the loop, but it's not working, I get an invalid expression term error. I have also tried `@{ counter++ }` but that didn't work either.

```
<table border="1" style="width:762px;height:25px; border-style:1px solid #000; border-collapse:collapse; clear:both;">
@{
    int counter = 1;
}
@foreach (var person in @ViewBag.POLoopList)
{
    <tr>
        <td style="width:24px; text-align:right;">@counter</td>
        <td style="width:55px">@person.EstPhase</td>
        <td style="width:32px">@person.JCCategory</td>
        <td style="width:180px">@person.ItemsDesc</td>
        <td style="width:90px; text-align:left;">@person.Comments</td>
        <td style="width:57px; text-align:right;">@person.OrderQty</td>
        <td style="width:40px; text-align:center;">@person.OrderUOM</td>
        <td style="width:56px; text-align:right;">@Convert.ToDouble(person.Rate).ToString("N")</td>
        <td style="width:70px; text-align:right;">$@Convert.ToDouble(person.Pretax).ToString("N")</td>
    </tr>
    @counter++
}
</table>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7534915/simple-increment-of-a-local-variable-in-views-in-asp-net-mvc3-razor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `@` from `@counter++`:

```
<table border="1" style="width:762px;height:25px; border-style:1px solid #000; border-collapse:collapse; clear:both;">
            @{
                int counter = 1;
            }
            @foreach (var person in @ViewBag.POLoopList)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td style="width:24px; text-align:right;">@counter</td>
                    <td style="width:55px">@person.EstPhase</td>
                    <td style="width:32px">@person.JCCategory</td>
                    <td style="width:180px">@person.ItemsDesc</td>
                    <td style="width:90px; text-align:left;">@person.Comments</td>
                    <td style="width:57px; text-align:right;">@person.OrderQty</td>
                    <td style="width:40px; text-align:center;">@person.OrderUOM</td>
                    <td style="width:56px; text-align:right;">@Convert.ToDouble(person.Rate).ToString("N")</td>
                    <td style="width:70px; text-align:right;">$@Convert.ToDouble(person.Pretax).ToString("N")</td>
                </tr>
            counter++
            }
        </table>
```

Answer (score 2):

When inside of a foreach and you have not placed the variable within an html element, you do not need the @ symbol.

change:

```
@counter++
```

to

```
counter++
```

Additionally, here is a nice quick guide on [Razor Syntax](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/razor_syntax.asp)