# jQuery function to change value of "value" attribute on html element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there a way to use something like `$(".class").change(function(){` or `$("#id").change(function(){`, but to change the value the value attribute of an option element like so?

```
<select>
    <option value="changeThis">opt</option>
</select>
```

I'm using a for loop to generate each option of a select list from a relational database, so I need to have a function to automatically increment the value so they're unique.

---

**New code:**

```
<div class="facilitySelection">
    <select name="Facility" class="form-control">
        <option selected disabled>Select a facility...</option>
        @{
            var i = 1;

            foreach (var item in Model)
            {
            <option value="@i">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FacilityName</option>
            i++;
            }
        }
    </select>
</div>
```

---

**Newer code:**

I have a table of Facilities, with an ID and Name field. Now using a `foreach` loop to use the ID directly from the database rather than generating the number from a variable in the script block, to ensure the ID and Name from the database line up correctly.

```
<div class="facilitySelection">
    <select id="Facility" name="Facility" class="form-control">
        <option selected disabled>Select a facility...</option>
        @{  
            foreach(var f in ViewBag.Facilities)
            {
                <option value="@f.Id">@f.Name</option>
            }
        }
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Why not set the value of the options as you're generating them? I assume you're creating the options in JS?

Comment: @Thijs I edited in my code to the question.

Comment: so you're not generating the options in JS but you're using MVC or something. Why not run a counter there and use it for the value. That way you don't have to "fix" your problems on the client-side in JS. Perhaps this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7534952/1244780

Comment: @Thijs Yeah MVC. That works much better, actually .Thanks

Comment: @Thijs I've implemented your idea into my code. Works perfectly. I edited it in if you want to take a look. Thanks.

Comment: that looks like a good solution to your problem! Much better than doing it with JS.

Comment: @Thijs  I've changed it and made it better again.  :)  Instead of generating the number in the code, I now use the unique identifier straight from my database to ensure the ID's of each row line up correctly. Don't know why I didn't think of that from the start.  :D

Comment: I have wondered how you were relating the selected value back to your data at the backend. Sounds like you made (another) good improvement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You change attributes with the [`attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) function:

```
$("selector-for-the-option").attr("value", "new value");
```

You can also use [`prop`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) because the `value` of an `option` element has a reflected property called `value` (**unlike** `input` elements, where the `value` property is **not** the reflected property for the `value` attribute):

```
$("selector-for-the-option").prop("value", "new value");
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you kindly.