# Increment in view not showing the updated value Showing only Initialized value asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

**view**

```
@{var i=0} 

<span>@i</span> //showing only initialized value not showing i value 1 or 2 or 5 or some other value

foreach (var item in Model.Boxlist)
{
    <p>@item.name</p>

    i++; //increment i here.
}
```

**i** does not showing updated value only showing initialized value where i am wrong tell me please.p tag showing 5 times because **Model** has 5 items but not showing value of **i** 5.

Comment: You'll need to move the `<span>@i</span>` into the `foreach` loop.

Comment: @p.s.w.g i only want single value like 1 or 4 or 5 not 5 times that,s mistake in question i am going to edit question.

Comment: So, `<span>@Model.Boxlist.Count()</span>`?

Comment: @p.s.w.g that,s great thanks! one thing to know that why i value is not updatind according to loop?

Comment: Because you print `i` before the loop executes. If you move it to after the loop, you'll see that `i == Model.Boxlist.Count()`.

Comment: @p.s.w.g but i have seen some related answer. in every answer increment like that  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7534915/  see this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186881/discussion-between-asif-shakir-and-p-s-w-g).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're printing `<span>@i</span>` before the `foreach` loop ever executes (and therefore, before `i` is incremented). You can move the `<span>@i</span>` to after the loop to see the expected behavior:

```
@{var i=0} 
foreach (var item in Model.Boxlist)
{
    <p>@item.name</p>
    i++;
} 
<span>@i</span>
```

This will produce:

```
<p>Foo</p>
<p>Bar</p>
<p>Baz</p>
<p>Qux</p>
<p>Quux</p>
<span>5</span>
```

But presumably, you really want the `<span>5</span>` to appear before the `<p>`'s.

Ultimately, if `i` is just used to count the number of items in the list, then just use the [`Count()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.count) extension method from Linq, (or [`Length`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.length) if your model is an `Array`, or [`Count`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.icollection.count) if it's an `ICollection<T>`).

```
<span>@Model.Boxlist.Count()</span>
foreach (var item in Model.Boxlist)
{
    <p>@item.name</p>
}
```

This will produce:

```
<span>5</span>
<p>Foo</p>
<p>Bar</p>
<p>Baz</p>
<p>Qux</p>
<p>Quux</p>
```